# DllNotFoundException: LogitechSteeringWheelEnginesWrapper.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, logitech-gaming-software

I'm using logitech gaming sdk downloaded from Assets Store. When I try to use their sample script it gives the error shown below:

> DllNotFoundException: LogitechSteeringWheelEnginesWrapper.dll
>   LogitechSteeringWheel.Update () (at Assets/Logitech SDK/Script Sample/LogitechSteeringWheel.cs:53)

LogitechSteeringWheel.cs:53 :

> if(LogitechGSDK.LogiUpdate() && LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0)){

The Dll in the 'Assets/Logitech SDK/Lib/GameEnginesWrapper/x64' and 'Assets/Logitech SDK/Lib/GameEnginesWrapper/x86' path.
When I tried run the program on different PC with same unity version, it works without any error.
What would cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things over time, but the solution is as simple as possible. In "LogitechSteeringWheel.cs" script there are dll importing lines. Instead of writing only the dll's name, I wrote full path. It works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me in
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/logitech-gaming-sdk-6630#reviews

jeromeWork posted:
Download the STEERING WHEEL SDK from here: https://www.logitechg.com/en-gb/innovation/developer-lab.html Unzip 
then navigate to: LogitechSteeringWheelSDK_8.75.30\Lib\GameEnginesWrapper\x64 
copy LogitechSteeringWheelEnginesWrapper.dll and overwrite the same file in your asset folder: \Assets\Logitech SDK