# Logitech SDK steering wheel LogiIsConnected false every time

Tags: unity-game-engine, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm building a game with Unity and I'm using Logitech steering wheel. Now I need to intercept the button clicked of the Logitech steering wheel but I'm not able to make this.

This is my code:

```
if (LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(0) && LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(0, 23))
{
    isReactionAlreadyGiven = true;
    float reactionTime = Time.time - dotDisaplyAtTime;
    Debug.Log("Reaction Time RT : " + reactionTime);
    RedDot(false);
    dotDisplayReactTime.Add(reactionTime);
}
```

Note, the two condition are FALSE every times, but in the game if I try to use steering wheel I'm able to turn the car, break the car etc.
How can I fix them?

Comment: Either you have another id in `LogitechGSDK.LogiIsConnected(id)` and `LogitechGSDK.LogiButtonIsPressed(id, 23)` or the button with button-id 23 is not used. So you might have to check if the ids are correct by some code before, or you just --quick and dirty-- have to enter the correct ids statically.

Comment: How can I find the correct id of my LogitechGSDK?

Comment: found out that the problem might be something else, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563214/dllnotfoundexception-logitechsteeringwheelengineswrapper-dll

Comment: I see that post but not working for me